# Bootstrap: How to link to another page and then program that page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is a really stupid question, but I am having a brain fart. I want to go to one of the other pages on my webpage and then program that webpage. What happens now is that I will click on the link to the other page, but it will still show the main page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "program that webpage" What are you trying to do? Where's your code?

Comment: I just simply what to make that page. Here is the link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/vjo6wyyg/ . For example, I want to click on the products page, go to that page, and then use HTML and CSS to put my information in.

Comment: @JakeLantzman I flagged this for close, as you are asking for a tutorial. While you linked to a JS fiddle, it was not in your question body. You even introduced the question by saying it was stupid. While there are no stupid questions, there _are_ poor ones. Next time, please include code snippets of current code. Focus the question about an idea, issue, code error, etc. Not something for a recommendation or "how to". The solution you chose is simple enough to find online. It involved directing a link to a file, rather than a url. It does not have to do with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple link like this you mean? You must have the physical 
file in your project. In this example it'll have to be named `FirstPage.html` and `SecondPage.html`

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="../FirstPage.html">First Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="../SecondPage.html"></a>Second Page</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I was just having a moment

Comment: No problem you're welcome